# Dynamic Where Clause in EF Core 2.2

Tags: c#, reflection, ef-core-2.2

I want to dynamicly add a where clause to my LINQ query. I have the filter property  name and the filter property value, so I need to build something like this:

```cs
var assignmentListQuery = context.Assignments;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bookingStep.FilterPropertyName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bookingStep.FilterPropertyValue))
{
    assignmentListQuery = assignmentListQuery.Where(item => PROPERTYNAME == PROPERTYVALUE)
}

ar assignmentList = await assignmentListQuery.ToListAsync();
```

I've tried to get the propertyinfo of the property, which seems not to me here.

```cs
var item = context.Set<Assignment>().First();
object value = item.GetType().GetProperty(bookingStep.FilterPropertyName).GetValue(item, null);
```

Has anyone an idea on how to create this kind of where clause?

```cs
public class Assignment
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = nameof(Id))]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = nameof(OrderNumber))]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = nameof(ScheduledLoading))]
        public DateTime ScheduledLoading { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = nameof(CustomerOrderNumber))]
        public string CustomerOrderNumber { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = nameof(ArticleNumber))]
        public string ArticleNumber { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = nameof(Comment))]
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = nameof(CustomerId))]
        public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = nameof(Customer))]
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

That's the Assignment entity, the FilterPropertyName is e.g. "CustomerOrderNumber"

Comment: Post the code of `Assignment`, and the value of `bookingStep.FilterPropertyName` you're using.

Comment: In general, you'll need to fall back to constructing expressions using the methods on the `Expression` class.

Comment: This is the *fourth* question about dynamic LINQ and Where today. Are you guys part of a course or something? There are a *lot* of duplicate questions anyway, going back years.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries + "c# dynamic where clause" in your favorite search engine

Comment: `Where` expects an `Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>>`. There are many duplicate questions that show how to construct one. Most of the time though it's easier to just append different `.Where()` calls to a query based on some criteria, eg `if (useCustomer) {query=query.Where(item=>item.Customer == value);}`

Answer (score 5):

Thanks everyone. I got it working using

```
List<Assignment> assignmentList;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bookingStep.FilterPropertyName) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bookingStep.FilterPropertyValue))
                    {
                        assignmentList = await
                            assignmentListQuery.Where(e =>
                                EF.Property<string>(e, bookingStep.FilterPropertyName) ==
                                bookingStep.FilterPropertyValue).ToListAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        assignmentList = await assignmentListQuery.ToListAsync();
                    }
```

Comment: Out of interest, what is the SQL statement that this generates?  Is it sane, or does it actually pull the data back to the client and do the where clause locally?

Comment: @Neil [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-2.1) is a special  EF Core method that *"can only be used in LINQ queries"*, read - in SQL translation, so definitely data is not pulled locally.

Answer (score 1):

Building off @Doppelmoep answer (which saved me, btw), you can also use the special EF Core  EF.Functions.Like extension to dynamically generate SQL Like statements with dynamic PROPERTYNAMEs and dynamic SQL Like statements (with wildcards - %_[^] are valid wildcard characters in a SQL like):

```
assignmentList = await
                        assignmentListQuery.Where(e =>
                            EF.Functions.Like(EF.Property<string>(e, bookingStep.FilterPropertyName),
                             bookingStep.FilterPropertyValue)).ToListAsync();
```